# How can I fix "ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([128])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([128, 1]))" error?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to train GAN with below code:

```
def run_a_gan(D, G, D_solver, G_solver, discriminator_loss, generator_loss, show_every=250, 
             batch_size=128, noise_size=96, num_epochs=10):
 """
 Train a GAN!
 
 Inputs:
 - D, G: PyTorch models for the discriminator and generator
 - D_solver, G_solver: torch.optim Optimizers to use for training the
   discriminator and generator.
 - discriminator_loss, generator_loss: Functions to use for computing the generator and
   discriminator loss, respectively.
 - show_every: Show samples after every show_every iterations.
 - batch_size: Batch size to use for training.
 - noise_size: Dimension of the noise to use as input to the generator.
 - num_epochs: Number of epochs over the training dataset to use for training.
 """
 iter_count = 0
 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
   for x, _ in loader_train:
     if len(x) != batch_size:
       continue
     D_solver.zero_grad()
     real_data = x.to(device)
     logits_real = D(2* (real_data - 0.5))

     g_fake_seed = sample_noise(batch_size, noise_size, dtype=real_data.dtype, device=real_data.device)
     fake_images = G(g_fake_seed).detach()
     logits_fake = D(fake_images.view(batch_size, 1, 28, 28))

     d_total_error = discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake)
     d_total_error.backward()        
     D_solver.step()

     G_solver.zero_grad()
     g_fake_seed = sample_noise(batch_size, noise_size, dtype=real_data.dtype, device=real_data.device)
     fake_images = G(g_fake_seed)

     gen_logits_fake = D(fake_images.view(batch_size, 1, 28, 28))
     g_error = generator_loss(gen_logits_fake)
     g_error.backward()
     G_solver.step()

     if (iter_count % show_every == 0):
       print('Iter: {}, D: {:.4}, G:{:.4}'.format(iter_count,d_total_error.item(),g_error.item()))
       imgs_numpy = fake_images.data.cpu()#.numpy()
       show_images(imgs_numpy[0:16])
       plt.show()
       print()
     iter_count += 1
```

with

```
fix_random_seed(0)

# Make the discriminator
D = discriminator().to(device)

# Make the generator
G = generator().to(device)

# Use the function you wrote earlier to get optimizers for the Discriminator and the Generator
D_solver = get_optimizer(D)
G_solver = get_optimizer(G)
# Run it!
run_a_gan(D, G, D_solver, G_solver, discriminator_loss, generator_loss)
```

But I got an error that given in this issue:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-19-bc85cbbdf398> in <module>()
     11 G_solver = get_optimizer(G)
     12 # Run it!
---> 13 run_a_gan(D, G, D_solver, G_solver, discriminator_loss, generator_loss)

2 frames

<ipython-input-18-701b71b7afd2> in run_a_gan(D, G, D_solver, G_solver, discriminator_loss, generator_loss, show_every, batch_size, noise_size, num_epochs)
     28       logits_fake = D(fake_images.view(batch_size, 1, 28, 28))
     29 
---> 30       d_total_error = discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake)
     31       d_total_error.backward()
     32       D_solver.step()

<ipython-input-14-e1f56d791cff> in discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake)
     17   N = logits_real.shape[0]
     18   device = logits_real.device
---> 19   loss = (bce_loss(logits_real, torch.ones(N).to(dtype).to(device)))+(bce_loss(logits_fake, torch.zeros(N).to(dtype).to(device)))
     20 
     21   ##############################################################################

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction, pos_weight)
   2578 
   2579     if not (target.size() == input.size()):
-> 2580         raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))
   2581 
   2582     return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)

ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([128])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([128, 1]))
```

Actually, before this 2 code snippet, I did not get any error related to my implementation. All expected results return true values but when I'm trying to do these steps I failed, how can I solve this problem? I think the real problem consist of array size, but I do not know where I need to look.

After Ivan's answer I updated such code snippets like this:

```
  logits_real_loss = bce_loss(logits_real, torch.ones(N, 1).to(dtype).to(device))
  logits_fake_loss = bce_loss(logits_fake, torch.zeros(N, 1).to(dtype).to(device))
  loss = logits_real_loss + logits_fake_loss
```

and

```
  N = logits_fake.shape[0]
  device = logits_fake.device
  loss = (bce_loss(logits_fake, torch.ones(N,1).to(dtype).to(device)))
```

But I am getting other value error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-15-b089f365cd5e> in <module>()
      2   d_loss = discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake)
      3   print("Maximum error in d_loss: %g"%rel_error(d_loss_true, d_loss))
----> 4 test_discriminator_loss(answers['logits_real'], answers['logits_fake'],answers['d_loss_true'])

2 frames

<ipython-input-15-b089f365cd5e> in test_discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake, d_loss_true)
      1 def test_discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake, d_loss_true):
----> 2   d_loss = discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake)
      3   print("Maximum error in d_loss: %g"%rel_error(d_loss_true, d_loss))
      4 test_discriminator_loss(answers['logits_real'], answers['logits_fake'],answers['d_loss_true'])

<ipython-input-14-15d437ae3425> in discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake)
     17   N = logits_real.shape[0]
     18   device = logits_real.device
---> 19   logits_real_loss = bce_loss(logits_real, torch.ones(N, 1).to(dtype).to(device))
     20   logits_fake_loss = bce_loss(logits_fake, torch.zeros(N, 1).to(dtype).to(device))
     21   loss = logits_real_loss + logits_fake_loss

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction, pos_weight)
   2578 
   2579     if not (target.size() == input.size()):
-> 2580         raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))
   2581 
   2582     return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)

ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([10, 1])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([10]))
```

how can I proceed?

Comment: Hi Eilysh, could you copy the entire stack trace? I'm especially interested in knowing which line inside `run_a_gan` throws it. Is it at `d_total_error = discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake)`?

Comment: @Ivan I updated trace part,  thanks for your support!

Comment: @Ivan I updated issue, what can we do know?

Comment: @Ivan I posted whole code that repo I derived, do you have any idea about our value error :( ?

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that you are calling `bce_loss` with data that have incorrect shapes. Input and target must both have the same shape. Assuming `bce_loss` has been defined with `torch.nn.BCELoss`. In your case `inputs` have two dimensions (`dim=1` being *1*) while `targets` has only one dimension.

You can change one, or the other so shapes match. The easiest though is to change your `targets` when calling `bce_loss`. Change `torch.ones(N)` to `torch.ones(N, 1)` and `torch.zeros(N)` to `torch.zeros(N, 1)` to allow for the extra dimension.

Here's the line to change in `discriminator_loss()`:

```
loss = (bce_loss(logits_real, torch.ones(N, 1).to(dtype).to(device))) + (bce_loss(logits_fake, torch.zeros(N, 1).to(dtype).to(device)))
```

---

I would recommend breaking your code down, it will greatly help you track down bugs since you will know which call/line breaks! Something like:

```
logits_real_loss = bce_loss(logits_real, torch.ones(N, 1).to(dtype).to(device))
logits_fake_loss = bce_loss(logits_fake, torch.zeros(N, 1).to(dtype).to(device))
loss = logits_real_loss + logits_fake_loss
```

---

*EDIT* - As said above, you are using `bce_loss` which takes two tensors **of same shape**. If you start changing `.squeeze(1)` on the input data as well you will run in circles! Look at `x.shape`, its second dimension size is *1* since you're on MNIST. Messing with your training loop will break if you try using a multi-channel dataset (i.e. RGB images).

Anyhow, easiest way is to generate targets of same shape as the input:

- for `discriminator_loss()`:

  ```
  loss = bce_loss(logits_real, torch.ones(logits_real.shape)) \ 
         + bce_loss(logits_fake, torch.zeros(logits_fake.shape)
  ```
- for `generator_loss()`:

  ```
  loss = bce_loss(logits_fake, torch.ones(logits_fake.shape)
  ```

Comment: I have problem about other functions, can you help me ?

Comment: I updated all torch.ones(N,1) to torch.ones(N) and torch.zeros(N,1) stayed same. Again I got error in trace now it shows: ---> 20   logits_fake_loss = bce_loss(logits_fake, torch.zeros(N, 1).to(dtype).to(device))

Comment: Actually you can check whole code from here: ıukojjhttps://github.com/jasonbian97/Deep-Learning-Computer-Vision/blob/master/generative_adversarial_networks.ipynb

Comment: Do you have any idea??

Comment: I did it but it's not work :/ could you provide whole code snippet what you want to say maybe I am confusing??

Comment: I directly drived my .ipynb from: https://github.com/jasonbian97/Deep-Learning-Computer-Vision/blob/master/generative_adversarial_networks.ipynb

Comment: Your notebook ran without any errors. Are you sure this doesn't work?

Comment: In my local code, I used in function def run_a_gan() : d_total_error = discriminator_loss(logits_real.squeeze(1), logits_fake.squeeze(1)) can this squeeze(1) makes a problem? Because in actual repo, they do not use this squeeze part, but in my code includes it:/

Comment: I've run the notebook you provided (this version includes the `d_total_error = discriminator_loss(logits_real.squeeze(1), logits_fake.squeeze(1))` part) and it runs correctly. My question is, are you still getting an error?

Comment: If there is a .squeeze(1) in the code I did not get any error, but if the code not include .squeeze(1) I got error, how can we run this code without .squeeze(1)'s and without error. I have to get results without .squezee

Comment: I need to use like this: d_total_error = discriminator_loss(logits_real, logits_fake)

Comment: I have edited my answer, I hope it will work for you.